# Doctrine 2: bi-directional relation, Adding entity on not owning will not persist

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

Doctrine 2: bi-directional relation, Adding entity on not owning will not persist

```
class AuthRole
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AuthUser", mappedBy="role", cascade={"persist","detach"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $authUsers;
}
```

AuthRole is the not owning side

```
class AuthUser 
{
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AuthRole", inversedBy="authUsers", cascade={"persist","detach"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $role;
}
```

AuthUser is the owning side

if i add a user to the role the relation will not be saved and AuthUser->role is null;
Why is this and is this fixable.

i know that when you add a role to the user the relation is saved but thats not what i want.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your `addUser` function under the AuthRole entity:

```
public function addAuthUser(AuthUser $authUser)
{
  $authUser->setAuthRole($this); // important line
  $this->authUsers[] = $authUser;
}
```

If you use a setter, then loop over the entire array and call `setAuthRole($this)` on each.

Comment: of course you could do that but its a hack. Why do we have the ability to use cascade persist / addd to a arraycollection if it does jack squat when your persisting the entities.

Comment: No, that's not a hack. You're supposed to do this...Doctrine isn't magical (:

Comment: :) but why do we even have a cascade persist then for the non owning side.

Comment: You don't, that's not mentioned in the doc AFAIK